# 32 bit Adobe Reader invocation from 64 bit IE 11

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, pdf, webbrowser-control

So i have Internet Explorer installed on my 64 bit windows 8.1 machine along with 32 bit Adobe Reader 11.

If i browse any .pdf file inside IE it spans a 32 bit Adobe Reader process and displays the pdf successfully (Screen shot). 
[image]

However replicating the same via WPF/WinForms WebBrowser control fails to do so.

How IE which is running a 64 bit process invokes a 32 bit Adobe Reader ?

Comment: It could be something like "calling a 32bit outproc COM server from a 64bit host". But I couldn't find useful links with that search term.